# Configure DKIM with MailChimp

Tags: mailchimp, dkim

I'm configuring DKIM for my MailChimp campaigns.

What do i need to do, other then checking the 'authenticate this campaign' checkbox, in order for my domain to recognize MailChimp? Do i need to install openDKIM on my machine for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you select 'authenticate this campaign' then no installation is necessary as [MailChimp will pass its own](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/authentication-for-mailchimp/) DKIM/Domain Keys/SenderID/SPF records for you. Pretty nice!

If you’re set on using your own DKIM, you will definitely need to install openDKIM or another solution on your server.